# How do I get two variable from one line in a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to work out how to make a batch file take one line and set two separate values it is to backup a file.

For example back up `C:\programfiles` to `D:\`.

How can I get both of those values from one line of user input?

Answer (score 3):

Batch files can directly handle parameters %0 through %9.

```
%0 is the program name as it was called,
%1 is the first command line parameter,
%2 is the second command line parameter,
and so on till %9.
```

So, if you executed the command like this:

```
backup c:\Programs d:\
```

Within the batch file you could refer to these values:

- `%0` = `backup`
- `%1` = `c:\Programs`
- `%2` = `d:\`

Keep in mind that if you have spaces in the filenames without surrounding the entire path with quotes, it's not going to work the way you're wanting.

Comment: Batch can handle much more than the parameters %0-%9, please see `shift /? `   for more help.

Comment: Also, you can loop through %* if you have an unknown number of arguments, or more than 9.

Comment: In your batch file refer to the parameters as `"%~1"` `"%~2"` and you will not have any issue with `spaces` and `&` characters etc.