# batch file: display 2 input prompts on the same line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How can I run this on one line?

```
@echo off
SET /P fp="Read pages "
SET /P lp=" to "
pause
```

What I would like to get: Read pages 1 to 5

Comment: I think your question is already there [How do I get two variable from one line in a batch script][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16047343/2746994

Comment: @JohnDoe: Comments support only the `[link name](URL)` kind of link formatting. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear but this provides the sort of thing you are asking:

```
@echo off
set start=1
set end=5
SET /P "fp=Read pages %start% to %end%: "
pause
```

Batch isn't designed to get two sets of input on the same line, and print text between them.  You could do it by getting input on the top line and using a CLS and printing the second input line immediately afterward.  Try this:

```
@echo off
cls
set /P "fp=Read pages "
cls
set /P "lp=Read pages %fp% to "
echo %fp% %lp%
pause
```

Comment: Actually 1 and 5 are user inputs/variable values. When I run my batch file and enter the values, then 'Read pages 1' is displayed on one line and 'to 5' on the second line. I would like them to be displayed on a single line.

Comment: Such a simple solution, too bad I couldn't think of that, thank you.